# What does a return do in a PHP function?

Tags: php

I know this is a very newbie question, but I cannot understand the difference between echo and return in a function, and how 'return' affects a function!

Comment: Well with `echo` you print something out, while with `return` you just return something from a function and then you can do whatever you want with the returned value.

Comment: manual seems clear: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is even a dupe for that lol. There is really a dupe for everything :)

Comment: There sure is @Rizier123 well, pretty much ;-)

Comment: @Rizier123 TBH, here are the keywords I used in Google: "what is echo and return in php?" *lol* go figure, eh?